# Firefox Add-on that lists all open tabs urls in one tab as text links

Tags: firefox, restore, browser-tabs, session-restore

When firefox crashes and restarts there is a "restore previous tabs" page that opens in a single tab in the freshly restarted window.  Let's say I had 15 tabs open in one window when FF crashed, links to those open tabs are now listed on that "restore tabs/windows page" with check boxes next to them.  FF then just asks you to check the tabs you would like to reopen.

What I am wanting is an add-on that will do this whenever I want. Not just when FF crashes and restarts.

The reason I want this is due to the fact that I'm online most of the day researching several different things at a time.  We're talking major multi-tasking.  After a few hours I have several tabs open that are making my system run slower/internet slower as a result of so many open tabs.  But these open tabs aren't necessarily something I want to bookmark but I still need quick access to them in order to read the info on them or link to other page links listed on that page.

So if I was able to have ONE TAB that lists all open tabs as links, using the title of the tab as the text for the link (text only just like the "restore page" does) then I could close many of the open tabs leaving the "Tabs Urls Link Page" open.  Then whenever I needed to reference a tab I had opened I could just click the text link and it would open.  Once the tab is listed on the "Tab Urls link page" it can be closed but the reference text link to it will remain on the "Tab urls link page.  This would majorly cut down on my system having to keep all the things on all the individual tabs running simultaneously.  All it would need to keep running in the browser is that URL link page plus whatever tab I currently had opened.

In the past I have actually just left the "restore previous tabs" tab open and untouched so I can just use it for the above purposes but that's risky b/c THAT page may not show up again if FF happens to crash.  And I would like to be able to access that page without FF having to crash, b/c that doesn't happen often. And when it doesn't I can't find that page obviously.

PS: The add-on "Copy Urls Expert 2.1.0" isn't what I'm needing in case anyone was going to suggest it

Answer (score 3):

Someone showed me OneTab for Chrome last night, and I decided to start making one for Firefox. Feel free to fork from https://github.com/diracdeltas/tabulous.

EDIT: This is now in the Mozilla addon store (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tabstash/). If someone wants to help out by making a window that shows the list of open tabs with checkboxes to close them, I would gladly take that pull request.

Answer (score 2):

[One tab](http://www.one-tab.com/) for chrome seems to suit your need. It would be awesome to have similar stuff for Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is [Tree Style Tab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/tree-style-tab/) plugin.

[image: Tree Style Tab]

It does **not** stay in a separate tab, but:

- New FireFox opens links in "passive mode", e.g. they are to be refreshed upon the first opening. So there is *no problem having the whole hierarchy opened on FireFox startup* and activating whenever you need; **With this plugin, I usually have about 120 pages opened upon FF startup**.
- Due to most screens are wide, the content is usually narrower than the screen resolution. So it *makes a huge sense* to place it on the left or right side;
- A true hierarchical tree allows you to make true nested sections;
- You may set the plugin for opening a window as a nested child. This builds the tree with no need to drag them across the tree;
- Also, opening a *bookmarks folder* automatically builds a tree (see "SO-1" and "StackExchange sites..." on picture above)

Answer (score 0):

You could send the "Restore" page to Too Many Tabs, as I do, and it would be safe there.
It can be drawn down whenever you want it.